# How to load chart data from URL for reactd3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs, webpack

I was looking at [react-d3](http://www.reactd3.org/get_start/), and was wondering how to load chartData from a URL source (REST API, etc.) that returns JSON in the desired format. The examples only depict loading from file. I'm not familiar with the react, reactd3, webpack, and browserify stacks.

Anyone have suggestion on the simplest solution to my question? I assume this is client side code (when webpacked), so it would be based on AJAX and may have same cross domain restrictions to deal with for HTTP calls?

Comment: You should look into [Ajax examples on React Rocks](https://react.rocks/?q=ajax). You would need to implement your components in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use the patterns you are used to. React isn't a full framework per se, and it's easy to do `import $ from 'jquery'` from your react code and do a usual `$.getJSON(url...)`.

Of course, the usual cross domain restrictions would apply.